# Storing float in NSNumber gives weird results

Tags: objective-c, xcode, floating-point, type-conversion, nsnumber

I am having weird results trying to store a float value to an NSNumber. It doesn't seem to be storing correctly (or printing correctly). I feel like it is a dumb mistake, but I do not know what I am doing wrong. Here is my code:

```
team.nExpectedScore = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:estimatedScoreSlider.value];
NSLog(@"%f", estimatedScoreSlider.value);
NSLog(@"%f", [team.nExpectedScore floatValue]);
```

where `nExpectedScore` is a synthesized property of the `team` class declared as so:

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSNumber *nExpectedScore;
```

Although I don't think it matters, the number is initialized in the `team` class `init` method (which is definitely called):

`nExpectedScore = [[NSNumber alloc] init];`

Also, the `estimatedScoreSlider` is a `UISlider` with a range from 0 to 500.
With all of this, the two `NSLog` statements print the following with a random slider position:

```
2015-02-07 15:32:43.442 APP_NAME[3013:126937] 213.474030
2015-02-07 15:32:43.442 APP_NAME[3013:126937] 0.000000
```

I would expect the two numbers to be the same. Why are they different?

Comment: Somewhere, it appears that you might be reinitializing your xExpectedScore var which is causing it to appear as 0. You don't need to initialize a NSNumber var if you are going to be something like this later "[NSNumber numberWithFloat:estimatedScoreSlider.value]" as that returns an instance of NSNumber which initializes that var for you without you having to call the alloc init method. Try removing those statements for that var and report back.

Comment: NSLog(@"%@", team);  I'll bet you $213.47 that it's null.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about team?  It appears that your team object is not initialized because you are experiencing a nil behavior of NSNumber, by seeing 0.00 which is the float value of a nil NSNumber?

You need to first run:

```
self.team = [[WhateverObject alloc]init];
```

then  you can assign values to it's attibutes such as:

```
 team.nExpectedScore = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:estimatedScoreSlider.value];
```

Comment: Thanks that was it. I accidentally set team to reference a nil object